# Why are we taking the square root of the gradient in Adagrad?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, optimization, gradient-descent

This is how we update weights with Adagrad:

$$w_i = w_i - \frac{lr}{\sqrt{g_i+E}}$$

where, $w_i$ is the $i^{th}$  weight, $lr$ is the learning rate, $g_i$ is the gradient of the $i^{th}$ weight at all the timesteps and $E$ is epsilon to prevent division by zero.

Now why are we taking the square root of $g_i+E$, can't we just remove the root and just divide.

I know removing the root gives bad performance, but why does it gives bad performance on removing the root?

Comment: Please make sure your question is precise and understandable. (1) Your formula how to compute $w_{i}$ is wrong. (2) You extend your question in an answer. (3) You change notation from question to your answer. (4) It is hard to follow your question in your answer. Please avoid using prose text to describe parts of a formula. Use the exact mathematical formulations. This makes it easier to read and understand.

Comment: Just compare this formula to the formula in your other post (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/wouldnt-it-make-more-sense-to-give-less-importance-to-gradient-far-away-in-past)

Comment: Also, it looks like a duplicate of https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/wouldnt-it-make-more-sense-to-give-less-importance-to-gradient-far-away-in-past

Comment: @Graph4MeConsultant Both the formulas are same, just I have used some different variables this time, which doesn't matter.

Comment: @Graph4MeConsultant I haven't even computed $w_i$ in the question, it's just the $i^{th}$ weight, what are you talking about?

Comment: @Graph4MeConsultant Please read both questions carefully, they both are asked by me, and are not at all the same

Comment: 1.) You have two question about AdaGrad, both asking about the interpretation of the scaling factor. So once you understand the scaling factor, you can answer both of your questions.  2.) Still your presented formula of how to compute $w_i = w_i - \ldots $ given the old weight is wrong.

Comment: @Graph4MeConsultant I still don't see what's wrong in the formula, can you please say the correct formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are taking the square root of $G_i$  because $G_i$ is the sum of squares of the gradient of weight $i$ from iterations $1$ to the current iteration. Since we squared all the gradients of all timesteps, $G_i$ was very large, and so we take its square root. Now you may think that, then why don't we just add the gradients instead of squaring the gradients, then adding. The answer to this question is that we square it to prevent negative gradients, so that negative gradients and positive gradients don't cancel each other out. Now you may think that why don't we take absolute value of the gradient then, the answer to this question is
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48267/mean-absolute-error-or-root-mean-squared-error/48268#48268)

That post was about root mean squared error or mean absolute error.

If you think carefully, these both issues are the same.

So, we take the square and not the absolute value. Now you may think that why don't we  power the gradient to some even power, why only square? Now, I leave this question to the consideration of the reader