# Why sparse features should have bigger learning rates associated? And how Adagrad achieves this?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, optimization, gradient-descent

I was learning about Adagrad optimizer. I came to know that it has a very helpful functionality which is that we can have lower learning rates for the features that are more common and greater learning rates for the features that are less common (or more sparse) when using Adagrad.

Now, why do we even want to have lower learning rates for the features that are most common?
Why do we even care if one feature is more sparse than any other feature?

Comment: @JavierTG Yes, now  the question is exactly correct and that is what I was trying to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Intuition behind learning rates

With Adagrad, **parameters** that model the influence of the **features** in our problem tend to be updated at the same rhythm, something that is accomplished by what you explained in your question $\rightarrow$ the parameters are updated with different learning rates/ steps which may depend on how frequent (or sparse) the features are.

But why the parameters that we are learning should be updated with different learning rates? $\rightarrow$ For example, if our cost function was $f(x,y,z) = 20x^2+y^2+z^2 \rightarrow$ and $x,y,z$ were our parameters, it is clear that having a point far away from the global minimum, the function will be more sensitive to changes on $x$ than on $y$ or $z$. But the same parameter step applied to $y$ and $z$ will lead to the same change on our cost function $f(x,y,z)$.

In the general case, when we don't know exactly the terms of our cost function, one conservative rule for updating would be to use smaller learning rates on the directions with "big" gradients. This would prevent us from overshooting on these directions if the decision of moving along them with a big step was wrong.

To visualize the previous reasoning we can plot how would be the paths followed by our parameters applying different learning rates to them. In this case, the hypotetical cost function that I have used is $f(x,y)=20x^2+y^2$ and the number of iterations made are the same in all of them ($20$). With this plots we can see that:

- **Left plot** $\rightarrow$ Applying a "big" learning rate to both $x$ and $y$ directions lead to overshooting on the $x$ direction, which causes that the path doesn't reach the minimum.
- **Center plot** $\rightarrow$ Applying a "small" learning rate to both $x$ and $y$, solves the issue of overshooting, but causes the learning to be very slow.
- **Right plot** $\rightarrow$ Applying a "small" learning rate to $x$ than to $y$ not only solves the issue of overshooting on the $x$ direction, but also makes faster the optimization.

*Note that the optimization used here is not exactly like Adagrad optimization, but with it I pretend to show the effects of different learning rates.*

[image]

### Adagrad

With Adagrad we are able to take this previous intuition of why the learning rates should be different for each parameter but with another point of view.

For understanding why Adagrad behaves in the way described by the question, we should take a look at the practical formula that is commonly used for applying it:

$$ \mathbf{w}_{t+1}= \mathbf{w}_t - \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\epsilon I + \text{diag}(G_{t+1})}}\,\,g_{t+1} $$

Where $\mathbf{w}$ is the vector of parameters that we want to update, $g$ is the gradient of the cost function w.r.t. these parameters $\mathbf{w}$, $t$ is the number of the iteration taking place and $G_t$ is given by:
$$G_{t+1}=\sum_{\tau=1}^{t+1} g_\tau\,g_\tau^T$$

So, if we have a look at one parameter $w^j$ from the vector $\mathbf{w}= [w^1,w^2,...,w^n]^T$, we have:

$$ w_{t+1}^j = w_t^j - \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\epsilon + G_{t+1}^{jj}}}\,\,g_{t+1}^j \,\,\,\,\,\, \leftrightarrow \,\,\,\,\,\, G_{t+1}^{jj}=\sum_{\tau=1}^{t+1}(g_\tau^j)^2$$

What does this mean? $\rightarrow$ As $t\uparrow\uparrow$ the learning rate related to the parameter $w^j$ will tend to decrease. This is because in the denominator we have the cummulative sum of the absolute value of its previous gradients.

Thereby, using Adagrad we could also solve the problem presented in the previous plots. Due to the fact that the plotted function was more sensitive to changes on the $x$ direction (hence the x-component of the gradient was bigger), Adagrad will *automatically* give a lower learning rate to the updates in $x$ than on $y$.

### But what is the relation of the above with the more/less common features?

Common features here take the meaning of features that during a significant number of updates their influence on the problem has been poorly analysed. This can happen because during these iterations the components of the gradient vector related to these features have had significant lower magnitudes.

Let's look at an example using Stochastic Gradient Descent $\rightarrow$ we will be updating the parameters for every single sample that we have.

Let's consider that our model of parameters is linear, and have two parameters $(w^{(1)},w^{(2)})$ that have to be trained $\rightarrow$ so we can have a predictive function like this:
$$\hat{y} = w^{(1)} x^{(1)} + w^{(2)} x^{(2)}$$

where $x^{(1)}$ and $x^{(2)}$ are the features of our problem.

So if we make use of a cost function ($J$) that represents the mean squared error of the prediction ($\hat{y}$) given by our parameters, the gradient at iteration $t$ will be given by a quantity proportional to the features:

$$ g_t = \left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial w^{(1)}_t}, \frac{\partial J}{\partial w^{(2)}_t}\right)^T \propto (x^{(1)}_t, x^{(2)}_t)^T $$

Thereby, using SGD the quantity that we use to update each of our parameters $\delta w_{t+1}$ is also proportional to the associated feature:
$$ \delta w_{t}^{(j)} \propto x^{(j)}_t$$

With this already set up, lets imaging that our training is done in three samples (just for visualization purposes). During these samples the $x^{(1)}$ feature is more frequent (or less sparse) than the other feature $x^{(2)}$, so we have a dataset, $\mathbb{X}$, similar to the next:

$$ \mathbb{X} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
5 & 0\\
3 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Where each row represents a sample of $x^{(1)}_t$ and $x^{(2)}_t$, with $t\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Now it is clear that the parameter $w^{(2)}$ won't be updated until the last sample ($t=3$), because during the first two samples ($t=1, 2$) its gradient component has been zero (becase its proportional to $x^{(2)}_t$).

But what would have happened at this point to $w^{(1)}$? $\rightarrow$ it would have been updated during the first two samples (non-zero gradient component), and because of it, its associated learning rate will be smaller than the one of $w^{(2)}$ in spite of having the same $x^{(1)}_3 = x^{(2)}_3$!

So now we understand why the parameters associated with sparse features can be updated with greater learning rates using Adagrad.

### Conclusion

Adagrad allows us to give more importance to updates in parameters that have associated features which are sparse, or more generally, to give more importance to parameter updates that have experimented a record of relatively lower gradients (in magnitude).

*Why is this useful?* To answer this, we can cite the original authors (see paper: "[Adaptive Subgradient Methods for
Online Learning and Stochastic Optimization](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume12/duchi11a/duchi11a.pdf?source=post_page---------------------------) "):

*> "Our procedures give frequently occurring features
very low learning rates and infrequent features high learning rates, where the intuition is that each
time an infrequent feature is seen, the learner should “take notice.” Thus, the adaptation facilitates
finding and identifying very predictive but comparatively rare features"*

Comment: Sorry, but I see that you are trying to explain ' why different learning rates for different features', but my question was 'why higher learning rates for the features that are more common'. I understand why do we use different learning rates for different features, but do not understand why do we use higher learning rates for more common features

Comment: Please can you link the site where that conclusion is reached?

Comment: Sorry but my question said 'Why do we even want to have greater learning rates for the features that are more common?', which was wrong, the correct question was 'Why do we even want to have lower learning rates for the features that are more common'. Sorry for this, I have edited the question. Here is the [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/82167/104959). At the end, the conclusion is reached

Comment: The edit on my post may help you now

Comment: OMG!, Your answer is just too clear and amazing. Thank you for this, thank you for spending so much of your time writing this answer for me!!! I can't upvote as I don't have enough reputation. But, your answer really helped me a lot. Thank you again!!!!

Comment: I would upvote this 20 times if I could. Very will written.

Comment: @JavierTG Nice answer! With regards to the last example, what would happen if we scaled our features so that the two 0's might disappear? I can't understand what count as a sparse feature.

Comment: (1/2) Hi @adosar, *features* refer to input data dimensions. *Sparse features* refer to those that have had little influence during training of certain parameters.  In other words, these sparse features consistently lead to low-maginute gradients for a certain subset of the parameters. In my toy example, the feature $x^{(2)}$ is sparser than $x^{(1)}$ since it consistently yields zero gradients for the parameter $w^{(2)}$, while  $x^{(1)}$ has yielded higher gradients for the parameter $w^{(1)}$.

Comment: (2/2) The key takeaway is that features influence model parameters differently. With Adagrad, a parameter influenced by sparse features ($w^{(2)}$ in the toy example) that suddenly produce a higher gradient, will get a larger update than those parameters that have been frequently updated ($w^{(1)}$ in the toy example).

Comment: @JavierTG Appreciate the elaboration. I was rethinking what I said about the scaling and I don't think it matters. Take a dataset where most content lies in the center of the image. In this case neurons of an MLP shouldn't be much affected by the boundary pixels, and as such the gradients of the corresponding to these parameters will be lower (get smaller updates). Is this a correct understanding of sparse features (beyond 0 values)?

Comment: @adosar I think it is bit hard to gain intuition from more complex models like MLPs. Following your example, if the majority of useful content in an image lies at the center, boundary pixels aren't necessarily *sparse features*. This is because the model should learn to ignore them via non-zero gradients during training. Instead, if a subset of parameters (weights and biases) have received smaller updates (because of lower-magnitude gradients) compared to others, then if a certain input image produces higher-magnitude gradients for these parameters, these will suffer less damping with Adagrad.